# How is this Stored Procedure wrong?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to delete everything associated with the userID sent as parameter to this procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `deleteUser`(userid INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE v_userid INT;

SET v_userid = userid;
DELETE * FROM Reply where user_id = v_userid;
DELETE * FROM Post where user_id = v_userid;
DELETE FROM Users where user_id = v_userid;
END
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that          corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''deleteUser' (userid INT)

Comment: ideally user table should have a relationship to post and reply tables via a foreignKey and the update/delete action should be cascaded to child tables. This procedure would then be unnecessary..

Comment: The keys are all in place! I just need this because there is a requirement to have a procedure for this project.

Comment: try specifying `IN` in front of userid

Comment: @pala_ That did not work either

Comment: Remove the backticks around the name?

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing `DELIMITER`

It should look like

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `deleteUser`(userid INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE v_userid INT;

SET v_userid = userid;
DELETE * FROM Reply where user_id = v_userid;
DELETE * FROM Post where user_id = v_userid;
DELETE FROM Users where user_id = v_userid;
END //
```